# Can Linux differentiate between HTTPS and OpenVPN traffic?

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, https

If I have a linux server that is receiving both HTTPS and OpenVPN traffic on the same port (TCP 443), and I can't change either server port, how can I redirect just the OpenVPN traffic to a different server?

From what I've read, at the protocol level, HTTPS and OpenSSL are different, and SPI can identify the difference. How can this be done in Linux?

Comment: The IANA assigned port for OpenVPN is 1194. Cisco SSL VPN often defaults to 443, please clarify what VPN is actually in use

Comment: @Bruno9779 OpenVPN offers a "stealth" mode whereby the server can run on tcp/443. This question asks how to separate true https traffic from OpenVPN "stealth" traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the OpenVPN man page (`man openvpn`) it tells you how to do something similar:

Quoting directly from the man page:

> **`--port-share host port [dir]`**
>                 When  run  in TCP server mode, share the OpenVPN port with another application,
>                 such as an HTTPS server.  If OpenVPN senses a connection to its port  which  is
>                 using  a  non-OpenVPN  protocol,  it will proxy the connection to the server at
>                 host:port.

Have your web server to listen on a different port, such as `localhost:40443`, and configure OpenVPN to proxy inbound connections to that target.

I'm not aware of any way to have the inbound traffic separated at ingres; you would have to do that on the server running OpenVPN.

Comment: This works, and solves my problem. The one downside of doing it this way that I can see is the fact that if the OpenVPN service stops running, HTTPS traffic stops too. Anyone know of any other ways to do this?

Comment: @Tal if you're looking at providing a resilient service you might be able to use a load-balancer on the front end.

Comment: A load balancer would probably work, but would require additional servers to be configured, adding to complexity. I was wondering if there was some way to use iptables to tell the difference between HTTPS and OpenVPN traffic, so I can send each to different locations. If that can't be easily done, I'll probably end up implementing your `--port-share` suggestion

Comment: the point of the stealth mode in OpenVPN is that it's (supposedly) "very hard" to tell the difference. The easiest place at which the difference can be detected is at the endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [sslh](https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh), a tool which is designed for this purpose:

What is sslh?

sslh is a protocol multiplexer. It accepts connections in HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, OpenVPN, tinc, XMPP, or any other protocol that can be tested using a regular expression, on the same port. This makes it possible to connect to any of these servers on port 443 while still serving HTTPS on that port.